# Object reference error in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

This is part of a windows form application which prompts a user to "Please enter a sales order" and then will open up a CAD drawing. However, I'm getting an error at "dsDoc = dsApp.GetActiveDocument()". Can anyone help me out with this one? Thank you!

```
 Private Sub startButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles startButton.Click
    Dim salesOrder As Integer
    If Int32.TryParse(txtboxSalesOrder.Text, salesOrder) Then
        If salesOrder > 99999 AndAlso salesOrder <= 999999 Then
            Using process As Process = New Process
                Dim ProcessProperties As New ProcessStartInfo
                ProcessProperties.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\DraftSight\bin\DraftSight.exe"
                ProcessProperties.Arguments = ("C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\JE5022AA.dwg")
                ProcessProperties.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                process.Start(ProcessProperties)
            End Using
            Dim dsApp As DraftSight.Application
            Dim application As Object
            dsApp = Nothing
            application = Nothing

            Dim dsDoc As DraftSight.Document
            dsDoc = dsApp.GetActiveDocument()
           'An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsApplication2.exe
           'Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

            If dsDoc Is Nothing Then
                Return
            End If
```

Comment: well, just a few lines before you have `dsApp = Nothing` and nothing in the next 3-4 lines initializes it, so `dsApp` is till Nothing/null when you try to `GetActiveDocument()` from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
dsApp = Nothing
' ...
dsDoc = dsApp.GetActiveDocument()
```

In this case, the *Object reference* is the variable `dsApp`.  When it says that it's *not set to an instance of an object*, that means that the variable is null (i.e. `Nothing`).  Obviously, since you are explicitly setting the variable to `Nothing`, it will always be null, so it is guaranteed to throw a `NullReferenceException`.

To fix it, you need to set the `dsApp` to point to the appropriate `DraftSight.Application` object rather than setting it to `Nothing`.

Comment: That was automatically generated from recording a macro earlier on. Do you have any suggestions as to what "dsApp" should be set equal to? Thanks!

Comment: Since I'm not sure what `DraftSight.Application` is, I couldn't say.  I assume that's a type imported from some third-party library.  It probably assumes that you will already have a reference to the current `DraftSight.Application` object somewhere and you just need to set `dsApp` to point to that object.  But since I've never used or heard of the library, that's just a guess.

Comment: you could try changing the line earlier to  `Dim dsApp As New DraftSight.Application` (and remove the one setting it to Nothing)  but, yea we have no idea what you are doing or working with

Comment: You could consult the [DraftSight SDK Documentation](http://www.3ds.com/support/documentation/developers-guides/).  I can't read their documentation for you because it requires a valid client login.

Comment: @Plutonix For the pedantic at heart: [Yea](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/yea.html)

Comment: Or, you could close this daily dupe.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I was the first to cast my vote.  What are you waiting for?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Ah, there it is :) Good call.  Wish I had thought to use the Dupe-Hammer with that canonical answer... Oh well.

Comment: @Plutonix Setting it to 'Dim dsApp As New DraftSight.Application' worked perfectly, thank you.